# Alexa Echo Beta SDK - Certificate issue

Tags: echo, beta, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

Amazon recently release Echo Alexa toolkit.

I received, registered my app. Alexa clearly recognizes my app exists. However it gives this error

> Request Identifier:
>   amzn1.echo-api.request.d969c196-8b3e-4169-99c8-20f566889760 The
>   certificate does not have a path to a trusted authority. This happens
>   if you are using a self signed certificate. Voice feedback Echo heard:
>   "alexa start myapp"

I verified my COMODO CA (COMODO RSA Certification Auth) is on the list of authorized CA. I ensured my certificate bundle was valid.

Is there anything specific I need to ensure my bundle.crt is in the correct order for Alexa? (there is no mention that .com is required, I am using .net)

these my COMODO filenames.

AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt

COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

mydomain-net.crt

ssl-bundle.crt

stn.private.key

Excited to get this to work ... please help

SA

Comment: I am now able to communicate with Alexa without issues. the source of the problem was the order of the certs and the incorrect directives in SSL and HTTP config files for apache. 

I used 

openssl s_client -connect 192.237.1.1:443 

to verify that the certificate 

   Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Initially I was able to confirm the error by code and searched and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I am now able to communicate with Alexa without issues. the source of the problem was the order of the certs and the incorrect directives in SSL and HTTP config files for apache.

I used

openssl s_client -connect 192.237.1.1:443

to verify that the certificate

Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Initially I was able to confirm the error by code and searched and fixed it.